# How to send Samsung knox message using API

Tags: api, samsung-knox

How to send Samsung knox message using API?

I think it must have some knox message open API, but I found nothing.
Is there any knox message API and example?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "messaging" capabilities of the Knox API. If you look at the Knox Premium API, you'll see the list of classes are clearly geared towards low-level device management for things like: VPN, firewall, app policy, security policy, etc.

See list of classes here:
https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-premium/reference/packages.html

Comment: thanks, you are right,
the knox message have no public API. you need contact samsung company to get these API document